# I want to prove Determine the coupon rate $r$, such that the price of the bond, at $T_0$, equals its face value

Tags: finance, bond

Consider a coupon bond, starting at $T_{0}$ , with face value $K$,
coupon payments at $T_1, . . . , T_n$ and a fixed coupon rate $r$. Determine the coupon
rate $r$, such that the price of the bond, at $T_0$, equals its face value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity,we let
\begin{align}
&\delta=\frac{T_n-T_0}{n}\\
&T_i=T_0+i\delta,
\end{align}
for $i=1,2,...,n$ we have
$$c_i=r\,\delta\,K.$$
The price, $p(t)$ at a time $t < T_1$, of the coupon bond is given by
$$p(t)=KP(t,T_{n})+\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i P(t,T_{i}),$$
we know the price of the bond, at $T_0$, equals its face value,thus we have
$$p(T_0)=K=KP(T_0,T_{n})+r\,\delta\,K\sum_{i=1}^{n} P(T_0,T_{i}),$$
then
$$r=\frac{1-P(T_0,T_{n})}{\delta\sum_{i=1}^{n} P(T_0,T_{i})}.$$
For more details, you can see [this link](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/15356)

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the concept of yield-to-maturity (YTM)? 
[Here](http://people.stern.nyu.edu/jcarpen0/courses/b403333/03yield.pdf) you find all necessary steps.
You first calculate using the current price and the cashflows. Then as you can see in the paper provided a bond with coupon rate equal to its YTM is priced at par (100) and thus the price equals its face value.

Comment: thanks @Richard & sorry for my delay. I'm new at this and would u explain that for me.

Answer (score 0):

I always thought doing $y(t,T) = \frac{-ln(P(t,T))}{T-t}$ was a quick good approximation, it applies when the bond price is calculated in continuous time